# Does meteor update mongodb version automatically?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have Meteor 1.2.2 installed and, according to MeteorBlog, it should comes Mongodb v3.0 or higher installed.

However, if a go on Mongo shell (meteor mongo) and do:

```
 $ db.version()
```

I get: 2.6.7

Shouldn't it be 3.0? I tried meteor update and it says all packages are up to date.

Is there a way to update Mongodb to the latest version as accepted by Meteor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Meteor 1.1 came with MongoDB support up to version 3 and you're supposed to be able to use Meteor in production along a MongoDB 3.0 database without major problems.

However they decided to keep the 2.6 branch regarding the Mongo version shipped with the Meteor tool and wait until Mongo 3.0 is mature enough before including it along official Meteor releases.

It means that Meteor updates its internal tool MongoDB version automatically, but at their own pace.

The local Mongo environment shipped with the Meteor development tool is something different than the actual Mongo deployment you usually use in production, and it is not required that the 2 versions be the same.

Comment: Thanks Saimeunt! This clarifies everything. I should follow the Mongodb documentation then while developing in Meteor. By the way, are there any significant changes in the command line / arguments structure?

Comment: @saimeunt i have mongo version is 3.4.1 and in meteor mongo MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12 now i have to use property $arrayToObject in aggregate and the property will be available after 3.4.1 so how can i use that in meteor mongo?