# Check the mongodb version in meteor project

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm a newbie to meteor and mongodb. I just want to know how to check mongodb version in my meteor project. When i check it on using robomongo it shows 2.6.7. Can there be two versions of mongodb in local machine and meteor project? And when update into meteor 1.3 does meteor update mongodb version automatically?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519504/

Answer (score 18):

With your meteor application running in one terminal, open a separate terminal, change into the project directory, run the following from the command prompt:

`meteor mongo`